# JMeter returning different value than from tibco designer

Tags: jmeter, tibco

I am seeing some weird formatting going in with the JMeter response.  If I run the same request from the tibco designer, I am seeing correct values.

From Tibco designer:

```
<ns1:Month>07</ns1:Month>
<ns1:TotalTransactionAmount>58.77</ns1:TotalTransactionAmount>

<ns1:Month>08</ns1:Month>
<ns1:TotalTransactionAmount>20.53</ns1:TotalTransactionAmount>
```

From JMeter 3.0/2.11

```
<ns1:Month>07</ns1:Month>
<ns1:TotalTransactionAmount>5.877E1</ns1:TotalTransactionAmount>

<ns1:Month>08</ns1:Month>
 <ns1:TotalTransactionAmount>2.053E1</ns1:TotalTransactionAmount>
```

It seems the decimal is a place off and an E1 is placed in the value as well.  What is causing this?

Comment: how those numbers are created / stored? I.e. how do they look in the script?

Comment: The numbers are created via the sum() function in tibco, we are simply adding some numbers together and returning that total to the queue

Comment: I see. So either "Tibco designer" is just converting those numbers for user-friendly display, or there's some parameter / header that tells the server in which format the numbers should be returned. In first case, nothing you can do, in second, you'd need to replicate that behavior. Numbers are equal though, so might not even be important for perf testing.